# How to format cell on exporting RadGridView to HTML

Tags: silverlight, telerik

**Format cell on exporting RadGridView to HTML**

I am using Telerik Silverlight controls. Currently i am trying to export RadGridView to HTML.

The Grid exported correctly but there is a problem with the format of cell i.e. the text align in all cell to left.

Is there any way to format the cell i.e. in first column the text is align to left and on second one align to right or center.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code you're using to export the grid.